# Why does this code post data twice?

Tags: jquery, json, dom, post, if-statement

Why does this code post data twice ?

```
$.post("send/user/sent.php", { url: response, secret_key: secret_key },
function(data) {
    if (parseInt(data.succ_code) == 0){
        // facebook log fired successfully
        $('#sent').addClass('good');
        $('#sent').html(data.succ_mess+' '+data.point+' point(s) !');
        return true;
    } else {
        $('#sent').html(data.succ_mess);
        $('#sent').addClass('bad');
    }
}, 'json');
```

In the database I see two rows for every post.

But if I do this:

```
$.post("send/user/sent.php", { url: response, secret_key: secret_key },
function(data) {
        // facebook log fired successfully
        $('#sent').addClass('good');
        $('#sent').html(data.succ_mess+' '+data.point+' point(s) !');
        return true;
}, 'json');
```

The data is just sent one time (good).

Can I make the `if` statement in `$.post()` success result without this happening?

Comment: Yes you can write any valid javascript code in the success callback. When are you executing this code, can you post some more code which triggers $.post().

Comment: $.post() is triggered by click function :(

Comment: Is the same data sent twice - are both rows identical? IOW, which data is being posted, the if or the else?

Comment: Can you check if the click event is not attached multiple times by putting an alert in the click event handler?

Comment: Any console errors? Have you verified what `data` contains? Is part of a form submission? You'll need to post more JS and perhaps HTML.

Comment: no it doesn't trigger another element, because securitykey posted are same. not different. and i putting alert outside $.post() function it's only trigger once. but if  i put it in $.post() function it will trigger twice.

Comment: @Gunslinger_ -- no `return` on an ajax call -- it does nothing.

Comment: Are you not going to provide more information???

Comment: error console returns nothing. all syntax is good. and problem solved. thanks guys

Comment: why you doesn't test it than downvoted it downvoter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code you might want to use:

```
$.post("send/user/sent.php", { url: response, secret_key: secret_key },
    function(data) {
        switch (parseInt(data.succ_code)){
        case 0: $('#sent').addClass('good').html(data.succ_mess + ' ' + data.point + ' point(s)!'); break;
        default: $('#sent').addClass('bad').html(data.succ_mess); 
        }
    }, 'json'
);
```

Comment: How would that produce a different result?

Comment: +1 accepted ! that's will switch and break, nice idea btw :) thx

Comment: @patrick-dw No clue but when debugging a problem it's always nice to start from a position of having decent code though, don't you agree?